# Using Box2d with Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have the following class:

```
#include "Box2d.h" 
#include "cocos2d.h" 
#include "cocos-ext.h" 

class BPBody:cocos2d::extension::CCPhysicsSprite
{   
...    
}
```

In the Application.mk file i have the following tag:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1
```

But in my class i cannot use `this->setPTMRatio` or `this->setB2Body` . I have searched everywhere and cannot find what i am doing wrong. Could anyone please help me ? What am i missing ?

Comment: What is the error reported? Have you #include <CCPhysicsSprite.h>?

Comment: It says that the class BPBody does not have any function called setBPMRatio or setB2Body ? The class has the functions but they are surrounded by #if CC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION pragma? How do i get this to work ? How am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Then, I am not sure as I don't use cocos2d. But, I suspect you actually didn't enable CC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION in your configuration file. Maybe try to split the flags: APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1 ?

Comment: No Tried this too. Nothing happened.

Comment: Try this #include "Box2D/Box2D.h"

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to define:

```
-DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1
```

in libExtensions project, so in your Android.mk of libExtensions, there must be something like this as well:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS := -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1
```

Answer (score 0):

compile with CC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=0